# Java 6 parsing routine is truncating a SQLquery

Tags: java, mysql

This is regarding Java and MySQL question. I have this excerpt:

```
String selectString = "select";
int selectIndex = config.getMappingSql().toLowerCase().indexOf(selectString);
int fromIndex = config.getMappingSql().toLowerCase().indexOf("from");

String subSql =config.getMappingSql().substring(selectIndex + Const.INT_6, fromIndex);

String callIdField = "";
String[] fields = subSql.split(",");

for (String field : fields) {

    if (field.contains(" " + pk)) {
        callIdField = field;
        break;
    }
}

String idSql = "select " + callIdField + " " + config.getMappingSql().substring(fromIndex) + " order by " + pk
```

The query in the variable `getMappingSql` is:

```
SELECT orktape.id, orktape.filename, orkuser.lastname from orksegment left join orktape on orksegment.tape_id=orktape.id left join orkuser on orksegment.user_id=orkuser.id where orktape.mediatype = 'A'
```

But the result is:

```
select  from orksegment left join orktape on orksegment.tape_id=orktape.id left join orkuser on orksegment.user_id=orkuser.id where orktape.mediatype = 'A' order by id
```

I'm not a Java programmer, but I think that the code is throwing away the values before the **"from"** because of the separator (the period between table name and column name). If this is true, is there a way to fix it, or will I have to reformulate the query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not knowing `pk` I can't test for sure but the issue is your for loop

```
       for (String field : fields)
        {
            if (field.contains(" " + pk))
            {
                callIdField = field;
                break;
            }
        }
```

At best `callIdField` will be set to 1 of the fields. As this is not setting anything your contains logic must be wrong.  Fix this to start and then you either need to concatenate callIdField as you go or use a StringBuilder.

Comment: pk is being set to "id" earlier in the class, which is valid in this case. This code works when the query is select column1, column2, from tablex. But I don't know enough about Java to understand what the period separator is doing to the parsing routine.

Comment: `field.contains(" " + pk)` should be `field.contains(pk)`.  This will return `orktape.id` with a final string of `select orktape.id from orksegment left join orktape on orksegment.tape_id=orktape.id left join orkuser on orksegment.user_id=orkuser.id where orktape.mediatype = 'A' order by id`

Comment: Andy, can you tell me how/why this code works with simple queries that do not include the period (table.column separator). In addition to fixing the problem, I'm really trying to understand this.

Comment: `field.contains(" " + pk)` is missing the period. Have you missed it out accidentally? `field.contains("." + pk)` is what I think you thought you had. This should work as you expect.

Comment: So, can I use an OR statement like: `code field.contains(" " + pk) | | field.contains("." + pk) ` to make it work with both types of queries?

Comment: Yes you can use the OR like that. I assume you're looking for id or something.id and avoid accidentally matching someidthing.field. if that's the case then it should work correctly.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help.